# ¿Cómo colocar en orden de fila, de la cantidad mas alta a la más baja en sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

¿Cómo colocar en orden de fila, de la cantidad mas alta a la más baja en sql? Tengo lo siguiente:

```
 SELECT grupos, SUM(puntuaciones)
 FROM juego WHERE grupos IS NOT NULL 
 AND puntuaciones != 0.00 AND grupos LIKE 'g%'
 GROUP BY grupos ORDER BY grupos;
```

Resultado:

```
 grupos  SUM(puntuaciones)
 grupo1  11
 grupo2  80
 grupo3  50
 grupo4  100
```

Me gustaría el resultado fuera:

```
 grupos  SUM(puntuaciones)
 grupo4  100
 grupo2  80
 grupo3  50
 grupo1  11
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT grupos, SUM(puntuaciones) AS total_puntuaciones
FROM juego
WHERE grupos IS NOT NULL
AND puntuaciones != 0.00
AND grupos LIKE 'g%'
GROUP BY grupos
ORDER BY total_puntuaciones DESC;
```

No lo probé, pero entiendo que debería andar. Le asignás un *alias* al `SUM(...)` para poder referenciarlo desde el `ORDER`. Como querés que ordene de mayor a menor, le indicás `DESC`.

Comment: Funciona perfecto. Muchas gracias